# Flutter Dart File path

Tags: flutter, file, dart, visual-studio-code, gpx

quick Flutter Dart issue.

I am trying to read from a text file located inside the app's directory, however Flutter does not recognize a single file path that I provide it. The file path is always responded to with "OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2".

I am trying to read from a file located in assets/importfiles, from a dart class inside lib/viewmodels. The assets directory has already been added to pubsec.yaml.

[Here is the picture of my directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDc1O.png)

I can even have the main class locate and print out the files' paths using rootBundle, but trying to initialize a new File using those paths provides the same error text.
If I were to use path provider to locate and read from files, how would I initially put the files into the Temporary Directory or Application Documents Directory, if Flutter does not recognize the file paths of the files that I want to insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just You need to remove folder name ''.

```
assets\importfiles
```

[image]

to

```
assets Or importfiles
```

[image]

Thanks You.Happy To help you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a "/" before "assets" in the file path?
I'm not sure that this will fix the error, let me know if it works!

Comment: I've tried, does not work. "./", "/", "\", ".\" all do not work as openers. Nether does changing direction of slashes.

Comment: I think is searching the file in the other "assets" folder. Does the complete path works if you copy that by right clicking on the file?